# Pandas 'type' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas, mypy, python-typing

I am trying to type a a function which receives a Series

```
from typing import Any
from pandas import Series


def func(w: Series[Any], v: Series[Any]) -> int:
```

However I got the error

> TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You probably want to do `Series.any()`

Comment: `pd.Series` does not support generics like that (only maybe in the most recent version?) Why did you *think* that it did?

Comment: also, in general, `SomeType` si the equivalent of `SomeType[Any]`, you probably don't want to use `Any`

Comment: It can be any type, I just to want to add some typing, this function uses the params as iterator

Comment: Adding only `w: Series` I got the error error: Missing type parameters for generic type "Series"

Comment: No, that is not an error. How, exactly, are you getting that error?

Comment: Yeah, pandas really have Series non-Generic, so use `from __future__ import annotations` (preferred, must be put at the very top of your file) or string annotation (`wt: 'Series[float]`)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the problem with missing generics is `mypy`-related, not runtime. It comes from incompatibilities between `pandas-stubs` and core `pandas`, so that stubs consider `Series` class generic, `pandas` does not, and so runtime raises if you attempt to specify type argument, and `mypy` is not satisfied if you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding quotes around the type will fix this issue.

In the code you provided:

```
from typing import Any
from pandas import Series


def func(w: 'Series[Any]', v: 'Series[Any]') -> int:
    # your code
    pass
```

Modern editors will identify the type and raise appropriate warnings or errors if violated.

You are not doing anything "wrong", since this won't have raised any warnings or error for builtin types i.e. list, dict, set, etc. However, using quotes is the safer choice since it will work in all these cases and yours as well.